# There there a way to get the current code workspace name for the bash scripts?

Tags: bash, shell-script

In linux environment, I create my git repositories under the directory -
`/myspace/darshan/repositories`

So there will be separate git repositories for each feature or bug that I will be working on.

I will have some common task which is same across different repositories like -

`building an image`

`copy an image`

`going to my component directory` etc

all of them would be in the same path except the root of the repository name.
ie, say building an image would be in the location -
`/myspace/darshan/repositories/<feature>/bin/sys/`

Here only thing that changes between repositories is the directory

I want to write some alias for the task which i have mentioned above -

`build`

`cp_image`

`goto_comp`

And I want all these alias to work correctly whatever depth I am in the workspace and whichever workspace I am under.

How can I create this setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is to use `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` which will output the base directory of the current repository. Thus, from any sub-directory of a git repository, `$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)` will be the base directory of that repository, and

```
cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/bin/sys
```

will always take you to the `bin/sys` sub-directory of the current repository.

Take care when using this outside a git repository — you should check that you’re actually in one first; `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` will exit with a non-zero exit code if it’s run outside a git repository, so you can use that.

Comment: wow... great. This is what exactly I was looking for. Thanks a ton.